# How to convert HAM Maidenhead Grid Squares into latitude-longitude?

Tags: php, mysql, leaflet, coordinates

In the mySQL database, I have coordinates of points in the HAM square format (e.g. `KO03ka`). Using this code I get geographic coordinates:

```
// fe user_loc = "KO03ka"

$loc = $user_data['user_loc'];

$lat= 
(ord(substr($loc, 1, 1))-65) * 10 - 90 +
(ord(substr($loc, 3, 1))-48) +
(ord(substr($loc, 5, 1))-65) / 24 + 1/48;
$lng= 
(ord(substr($loc, 0, 1))-65) * 20 - 180 +
(ord(substr($loc, 2, 1))-48) * 2 +
(ord(substr($loc, 4, 1))-65) / 12 + 1/24;
```

I want to add points to the map using `print json_encode()`. How to prepare the JSON file correctly? In the database I do not have lat, lng, only a square locator format.

```
$query = mysql_query("select * from maps");

$rows = array();
while($data = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
    $rows[] = $data;
}

print json_encode($rows);
$db = NULL;
```

Please help me prepare the JSON file for Leaflet.

Comment: If you want to do the conversion on the client there's a great JS library here - https://gist.github.com/DrPaulBrewer/4279e9d234a1bd6dd3c0

Comment: In data base i have HAM square format, how to prepare this format to lat, lng ?